# load the splash screem dynamically from web server in wp

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am developing windows phone 8 apps and the splash screen in the app should be loaded dynamically from web server. Does anyone know how i should implement that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly that's not possible using the default behavior - splashscreen must be located in root folder of your app with predefined file name.
What you can do though is simulate the start screen using initial custom page and show whatever you want there, something like Skype is using in their WP8 app.
Note, in WP8 apps it's no longer required to use splashscreens because the loading time for apps was significantly improved when comapring to WP7.

Comment: I have found a sample i think it would be useful. in sample i replace the image source with absolut url http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Custom_splash_screen_with_progress_bar_for_Windows_Phone_applications

Comment: It is a good news that loading time for wp 8 apps is improved. My app start with loading a xml and fetch all the data and save them in sqlite and then create all pages and widgets from saved data. therefore, I really need such screen shots for the installation

Comment: +1 on Martin's answer. ALso, for WP8 a lot of apps don't really need a splash screen if the first page loads fast enough. It's just distracting to see a splash screen image for less then a second.